# Better way to perform simple I/O in main

Tags: haskell, io

Quick question I've encountered while getting my feet under me in Haskell related to this quick test:

```
module Main where
main :: IO()
main = putStrLn (show (inc 3))

inc :: (Num a) => a -> a
inc x = x+1
```

Is there a better way to output the value of the inc function? I could not get output without using nested parens to force evaluation order. With fewer parens I receive type errors. Just figure there must be a better way.

Thanks if you can clear my head :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all: parentheses don't force evaluation order.

To get rid of parentheses you can use `$` which has very low precedence and thus allows you to get rid of parentheses for the last argument.

For this particular case there's also the `print` function which is defined as `putStrLn . show`, so you can do `print (inc 3)` or `print $ inc 3`.

Comment: A great help, much obliged. It's always the simple things that get me :)